# C# EF: How to search between two dates in EF but want to exclude time from data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i do not know how to execlude time from data when doing comparison in EF.

```
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        var query = from n in db.BDatas
                    orderby n.AddDate,n.CountryCode
                    where n.CountryCode=="GB" 
                    && (n.AddDate >= stdate.Date && n.AddDate <= etdate)
                    select n;
    }
```

i guess my above query will include date and time when comparision will occur. so tell me what to do?

Comment: Try with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx - `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.AddDate) >= stdate.Date && DbFunctions.TruncateTime( n.AddDate) <= etdate.Date)`

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to exclude time from SQL comparison. You can just exclude time from parameters which you are passing:

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    var startDate = stdate.Date; 
    var endDate = etDate.Date.AddDays(1);

    var query = from n in db.BDatas
                orderby n.AddDate,n.CountryCode
                where n.CountryCode=="GB" 
                && (n.AddDate >= startDate && n.AddDate < endDate)
                select n;
}
```

Note that I used `< endDate` and added one more day to it. Thus you will have results from any time of previous day.

Comment: And for little bit more convoluted scenarios you have `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()`

Answer (score 4):

If Your Field `AddDate` is a DateTime Field you can  do it as follows

```
    using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            var query = (from n in db.BDatas
                        orderby n.AddDate,n.CountryCode
                        where n.CountryCode=="GB" 
                        select n).Where(n => n.AddDate.Date >= stdate.Date &&
 n.AddDate.Date <= etdate).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: i am using EF6 but no date property is getting accessible for AddDate but AddDate is date time field

Comment: at my end AddDate.Date is not avilable only AddDate is avilable.

Comment: @Mou, What is the DataType of AddDate

Comment: AddDate data type is datetime.

Comment: If you are still waiting for fixing : please make it clear what you mean when you say <<at my end AddDate.Date is not avilable only AddDate is avilable.>>

Comment: my AddDate field is nullable type and for this reason date property is not there for AddDate.

Comment: Why don't you add different from null condition on your where clause
.Where(n => n.AddDate != null &&
            n.AddDate.Date >= stdate.Date && 
            n.AddDate.Date <= etdate)

Comment: A better where clause for nullable type.Where(n => n.AddDate.HasValue  && n.AddDate.Value.Date >= stdate.Date && n.AddDate.Value.Date <= etdate)
   BUT, putting C# in EF where clauses will only make EF work harder and take longer to process. Pre-determine the elements nulliblity somthing akin to https://stackoverflow.com/users/470005/sergey-berezovskiy post

Answer (score 0):

Using Entity Framework Core

Had a Model **"Fire"**, needed to pass date string to date from format **"yyyy-MM-dd"**

Injected my dbContext in my Service class

First cast date string to DateTime and used them to fetch records as shown below

```
    var sDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var eDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var fireData = await _dbContext.Fire.Where(b => (b.CreatedAt >= sDate && b.CreatedAt < eDate) && b.UploadStatus == "False").ToListAsync();
    return fireData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add one day
a simple way to use. Date
like

```
var query = from n in db.BDatas
            orderby n.AddDate,n.CountryCode
            where n.CountryCode=="GB" 
            && (n.AddDate.Date >= startDate && n.AddDate.Date < endDate)
            select n;
```